# How can I create an expanded table using html and angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to create an expandable table where there will be one header with plus icon to expand and the child will be displayed in the expanded part.

[image: enter link description here]

I am able to create that but the child rows are not coming below the parent row border that is happening because I am using the table inside the parent `td`. So is there any better way to use.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.carList = [{
    review: 'New',
    rating: 5,
    fiveStarPercent: 100,
    recommended: 'yes',
    price: '$1,000,000',
    name: 'Row 1',
    descrt: [{
      name:'Clild 1',
      review: 'New',
      rating: 5,
      description: 'test 1',
      card: 'N',
      gift: '$1,565,650'
    }, {
      name:'Clild 2',
      review: 'New',
      rating: 5,
      description: 'test 2',
      card: 'N',
      gift: '$1,554,540'
    }, {
      name:'Clild 3',
      rating: 5,
      review: 'New',
      description: 'test 3',
      card: 'Y',
      gift: '$1,444,450'
    }]
  }, {
    review: 'Poor',
    rating: 1,
    fiveStarPercent: 10,
    recommended: 'no',
    price: '$5',
    name: 'Row 2',
    descrt: [{
      name:'Clild 1',
      review: 'New',
      description: 'test ',
      card: 'N',
      rating: 5,
      gift: '$1,025,655'
    }, {
      name:'Clild 2',
      review: 'New',
      description: 'test 2',
      card: 'Y',
      rating: 5,
      gift: '$1,545,454'
    }]

  }];
});
```

```css
tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
tr.trigger:hover td {
  background-color: #ffc !important;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Items</th>
        <th>Card</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="trigger" ng-repeat-start="car in carList | filter:tableFilter" ng-click="main.activeRow = !main.activeRow">
    <td><a href="#">+</a><span style="padding:4px;">{{car.name}}</span></td>
    <td>{{car.review}}</td>
    <td>{{car.rating}}</td>
    <td>{{car.fiveStarPercent}}</td>
    <td>{{car.recommended}}</td>
    <td>{{car.price}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="main.activeRow" ng-repeat="subling in car.descrt">
    <td>{{subling.name}}</td>
    <td>{{subling.rating}}</td>
    <td>{{subling.review}}</td>
    <td>{{subling.description}}</td>
    <td>{{subling.card}}</td>
    <td>{{subling.gift}}</td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

This is the reference URL: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OsNSeJWUShkKlJBJYO2b?p=info)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Can't you see I had given an working example. First see if I want written a code or not don't say whatever you want.

Comment: Honestly, before I reformatted your question it was hard to tell what you were asking. My comment is a default comment for questions that seem to be low effort.

Comment: I also know that there should be some reference to ask any prbm. And you also should check before saying any thing if the reference is there or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid nested tables, so that will help issues related to `td` width

```
<tr class="trigger" ng-repeat-start="car in carList | filter:tableFilter" ng-click="main.activeRow = !main.activeRow">
    <td><a href="#">+</a><span style="padding:4px;">{{car.name}}</span></td>
    <td>{{car.review}}</td>
    <td>{{car.rating}}</td>
    <td>{{car.fiveStarPercent}}</td>
    <td>{{car.recommended}}</td>
    <td>{{car.price}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="main.activeRow" ng-repeat="subling in car.descrt">
    <td>{{subling.name}}</td>
    <td>{{subling.rating}}</td>
    <td>{{subling.review}}</td>
    <td>{{subling.description}}</td>
    <td>{{subling.card}}</td>
    <td>{{subling.gift}}</td>
</tr>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OsNSeJWUShkKlJBJYO2b?p=preview)

> I was not sure that `ng-repeat` and `ng-repeat-end` would work
>   together, but they did.